# Getting word count in a sentence without punctuation marks NLTK python

Tags: python, nlp, token, nltk, tokenize

I am trying to get the word count in a sentence with nltk in python

This is the code I wrote

```
import nltk

data = "Sample sentence, for checking. Here is an exclamation mark! Here is a question? This isn't an easy-task."

for i in nltk.sent_tokenize(data):
    print(nltk.word_tokenize(i))
```

This was the output

```
['Sample', 'sentence', ',', 'for', 'checking', '.']
['Here', 'is', 'an', 'exclamation', 'mark', '!']
['Here', 'is', 'a', 'question', '?']
['This', 'is', "n't", 'an', 'easy-task', '.']
```

Is there any way to remove the punctuation marks, prevent `isn't` from splitting into two words and split `easy-task` into two?

The answer I need is something like ths:

```
['Sample', 'sentence', 'for', 'checking']
['Here', 'is', 'an', 'exclamation', 'mark']
['Here', 'is', 'a', 'question']
['This', "isn't", 'an', 'easy', 'task']
```

I can kind of manage punctuation marks by using stopwords like:

```
import nltk

data = "Sample sentence, for checking. Here is an exclamation mark! Here is a question? This isn't an easy-task."

stopwords = [',', '.', '?', '!']

for i in nltk.sent_tokenize(data):
    for j in nltk.word_tokenize(i):
        if j not in stopwords:
            print(j, ', ', end="")
    print('\n')
```

output:

```
Sample , sentence , for , checking , 

Here , is , an , exclamation , mark , 

Here , is , a , question , 

This , is , n't , an , easy-task ,
```

but this does not fix `isn't` and `easy-task`. Is there a way to do this?
Thank you

Comment: Well, you need to define the set of punctuation marks which don't cause words to split, the set that do cause a split (you could just replace these with space), and possibly the set of punctuation marks that are ambiguous wrt. word-splitting (e.g. is `U.S.A.` or `i.e.` multiple words or one?) (Do you need to handle Unicode characters too?)

Comment: By the way, instead of using ` , ` in your output, people often use `|` vertical bar, because it's clear, self-explanatory, found in ASCII, but generally doesn't occur naturally in text. So: `Here|is|a|question`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use different tokenizer which can take care of your requirement.

```
import nltk
import string
tokenizer = nltk.TweetTokenizer()

for i in nltk.sent_tokenize(data):
    print(i)
    print([x for x in tokenizer.tokenize(i) if x not in string.punctuation])

#op
['Sample', 'sentence', 'for', 'checking']
['Here', 'is', 'an', 'exclamation', 'mark']
['Here', 'is', 'a', 'question']
['This', "isn't", 'an', 'easy-task']
```